# if $A$ subset of $B$ then $P(B)-P(A)=P(B\setminus A)\ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Let $P$ be a probability measure on $(\Omega, \mathscr{F})$, If $a,b,\in\mathscr{F}$ and $A\subset B$, then $P(B)-P(A)=P(B\setminus A)\ge 0$.

So far I have:

$A\subset B \implies B\setminus A = B\cap A^c = \emptyset$ as $A$ and $B^c$ are disjoint.
Since $A\cup (B\setminus A)=A\cup (B\cap A^c)=(A\cup B)\cap (A\cup A^c)=B\cap\Omega = B$

Then for $A,B\in \mathscr{F}\implies P(A\cup (B\setminus A))=P(A)+P(B\setminus A) = P(B)$ by countable additivity.

Rearranging, $P(B)-P(A)=P(B\setminus A) \ge 0$.

Comment: Since $A$ might be a proper subset of $B$, why is $B\cap A^c = \emptyset$?

Comment: You're right... if I let $C=B\backslash A$ then $A\cap C=\emptyset$. Not sure how this is used in the proof though.

Comment: Hint: $B = (A\cap B) \cup (A^c\cap B) = A \cup (A^c\cap B)$ is the union of mutually exclusive events $A$ and $A^c\cap B$.  So, apply additivity and stare very hard at the result, possibly thinking at the back of your mind that another name for $A^c\cap B$ is $B\\A$.

Comment: I see now, thank you! $A^c\cap B=B\backslash A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(B)-P(A) = P(B \cap A) + P(B \cap A^c) - P(A \cap B) - P(A \cap B^c)$,

but $P(B \cap A) = P(A \cap B)$, and since $A \subset B$ we have  $P(A \cap B^c)=P(\emptyset )=0$.

So $P(B)-P(A) =  P(B \cap A^c)$ which is $P(B \backslash A)$.

$P(B\backslash A)\ge 0$ comes from the definition of a probability measure.