# Prove: If $A \subset B$ then $P(A) \le P(B)$ and $P(B-A) = P(B)-P(A)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to prove the following theorem using the axioms quoted below.

> **Theorem:** If $A \subset B$ then $P(A) \le P(B)$ and $P(B-A) = P(B)-P(A)$

---

> **Axiom 1:** For every event $A$ in the class $C$,
>
> $$P(A)  \ge 0$$
>
> **Axiom 2:** For the sure or certain event $S$ in the class $C$,
>
> $$P(S) = 1$$
>
> **Axiom 3:** For any number of mutually exclusive events $A_1,
> A_2,\cdots$, in the class C,
>
> $$P(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots) = P(A_1)+P(A_2) +\cdots $$

For the first part, because $B = (B\setminus A) \cup (B \cap A)$ we have  $P(B) = P((B\setminus A) \cup (B \cap A))$ $= P(B\setminus A)+P(B \cap A) \ge  0+P(B \cap A) \ge P(A) $ therefore $P(B) - P(A) \ge 0$. Hence $P(B) \ge P(A)$.

However, I can't get anywhere for the second part. I know that $P(B-A) = P(B \cap A')$ but I don't know how to turn the intersection into union so that I can use axiom 3. How do I prove this?

Comment: You've done everything you need to do in the first part. $B-A=B\setminus A$, and $B\cap A=A$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/492056/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $B-A$ and $A\cap B=A$ are mutually exclusive and their union is $B$. One of your axioms handles that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Since $A\subseteq B,$ then $A\cap B=A.$