# Does $A \rightarrow B$ imply $P(A) \le P(B)$?

Tags: probability

My intuition is that if you have two events, $A$ and $B$, and you can show that event $A$ implies event $B$, then you should have $P(A) \le P(B)$ because any time A happens so does B, but not necessarily the other way around. Similarly then $A \leftrightarrow B$ implies $P(A) = P(B)$ because they'd just be different ways of talking about the same event.

I'm an undergraduate CS student who has recently started assisting with some machine learning research. As such I'm a little bit in over my head with some of the math, especially with probability theory. Even though I feel pretty confident about this I have no way to show it formally and my set-theoretic intuitions aren't always perfect. Could someone out there give me a more formal grounding for why this does or doesn't work?

Comment: yes this is true. this is about as formal as you can get. to be a little more though. if A implies B then B is always true if A is but B can also be true if A is not. the special case is when B also implies A and although it is not necessarily true that one is a different way of talking about the same thing they do always occur together so they will have the same probability.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/492056/321264

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A implies B is equivalent to $A\subseteq B$. The inequality follows immediately from the probability axioms.

Answer (score 2):

If $A\subseteq B$, then $B = A\cup(B-A)$. Once $A\cap(B-A) = \varnothing$, we have that
\begin{align*}
P(B) = P(A\cup(B-A)) = P(A) + P(B-A) \geq P(A)
\end{align*}

where we used the finite additivity property of the probability measure $P$.